# Gridview childitem call another class Listactvity in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-listview, android-gridview

I have custom gridview, When i click child item to open another listactivity class with in current activity. I have listactivity class is there. But how to call this activity. see this image

```
 List 1
 List 2                        GridChild Item2
 List 3

 GirdChild                      Gridchild item4 
 item 3
```

how to call this activity and pass some values. I have tried intent method, this is go another activity.

Comment: _"how to call this activity"_ and _"I have tried intent method, this is go another activity"_ ?? You're explanation is unclear. Do you want to go in other activity or not ? Do you only want to hide the gridview and show a listview ??

Comment: i don't know. but they want output from this method. Example i pad palystore check mobl21 app.

Comment: You don't know what you want ? I haven't a iPad :). Explain your issue correctly, because no one can help you if you don't know what you want :p

Comment: sorry dude.. I need ur help. i have create a new view on the child items. but how to access list activity methods and processing.

Comment: If you what to call an activity (a ListActivity IS an activity). You only have to use intent and it launch a new window.

Comment: i know this method. Activity goes next screen. how to access another activity and method. pls help last 2 days try this method. i don't know which way to call.

Comment: You can't. The activity is a graphical class. So you can only access to this method when it launch.

Comment: ok thanks!. I need another help for u.. if u see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696066/3-d-flip-animation-with-gridview-in-android

Comment: i want onitem click listener on relative layout. but realative layout not support on item click pls see this issue..

Answer (score 0):

Fragment interact more than two activity. When you click child item to open another listactivity class as a dialog based. Android manifest file set activity as dialog. Ex:

```
<activity android:name="contextListActivty" 
          android:label="context" 
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
```